# Managing litter box for cat with polyuria (increased urination)?

Tags: cats, urination

As cats get older, they commonly develop conditions such as chronic kidney disease or diabetes which leads to polyuria (production of large amounts of urine). Managing the litter box in these cases can be challenging as it quickly becomes oversaturated.

Obviously the litter box needs to be cleaned out regularly, but what other recommendations are there in terms of litter type and setup that work well to keep the litter box manageable for cats with polyuria?

Answer (score 3):

More and/or larger boxes.

The standard guideline is one box per cat plus a spare. Cats with polyuria are like having more cats, so add more boxes accordingly. Spread the boxes around the house so older or ill cats don't have to walk as far and will be less tempted to go somewhere inappropriate.

Larger boxes will accommodate more litter and thus more waste. Standard litter boxes are often too small anyway, especially covered ones, and can rarely hold more than one day's waste from one healthy cat. A larger box will also be easier for an older or ill cat to move around and dig in. A high-sided box also helps with cats that don't (or can't) squat properly. Storage totes are cheap and work well, though perhaps not aesthetically pleasing.